# Reduce a program's sleep() function

Tags: linux, sleep

I have a binary program developed for Linux which reads lines from a server's network stream. Its communication is encrypted in a way that would take me too long to figure out, so I can't rewrite it.

After outputting each line, the program calls `nanosleep(100000000)` (I found this using `strace`) However, when the server sends multiple lines in quick succession, there's a big delay between the actual stream and the output.

Since I don't have the source code of the program, my question: is there a way to reduce the sleep time of this software? "Accelerating" it?

For reference, the program is Punkbuster's [PBUcon](http://www.punkbuster.com/index.php?page=pbucon.php)

Comment: Is the sleep function called from a shared library? Then you might be able to replace with with `LD_PRELOAD` or some foolery like that.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It almost certainly does, in which case this would be easiest if he didn't mind potentially mucking with other sleep calls.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try the LD_PRELOAD trick:

```
/* nosleep.c */
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int sleep(unsigned int seconds)
{
    return 0;
}
int usleep(useconds_t usec)
{
    return 0;
}
int nanosleep(const struct timespec *req, struct timespec *rem)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Then compile with:

```
$ gcc -o libnosleep.so -shared nosleep.c -fpic
```

And then run your program with:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./libnosleep.so pbucon
```

There are a few things you should be aware of:

1. It will replace *every* call to `nanosleep`, not only the ones you don't like, and that can have subtle undesired effects. You could check for the particular values of the argument, if you feel you need it.
2. It will not work for suid/sgid programs.
3. It will work only for dynamic-linked programs, Not for statically linked ones.

**UPDATE:** If you want to chain the call to the original function, you can do the following:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int usleep(useconds_t sec)
{
    typedef int (*usleep_f)(useconds_t);
    static usleep_f real_usleep = NULL;
    if (!real_usleep)
        real_usleep = (usleep_f)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "usleep");

    printf("%d\n", (int)sec);

    if (...)
        return real_usleep(sec);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

If you wanted to avoid GNU extensions (`RTLD_NEXT` is one) you would have to discover the name of the shared library that contains the function, with for example:

```
$ objdump -p pbucon.run | grep NEEDED
NEEDED           libc.so.6
```

And then, in the function do:

```
    if (!real_usleep)
    {
        void *libc_so = dopen("libc.so.6", RTLD_GLOBAL);
        real_usleep = (usleep_f)dlsym(libc_so, "usleep");
    }
```

Comment: @DanielS - Indeed! Corrected.

Comment: @DanielS - `strace` lists the _system calls_, but the `LD_PRELOAD` trick replaces _library calls_. Sometimes they are the same, sometimes they are not. Sometimes many different library calls correspond to the same system call. That's why in the example I replaced `sleep`, `usleep` and `nanosleep`, although maybe others. I would bet that your program is using `usleep` (check it with `objdump -T pbucon.run | grep sleep`).

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly :) Just one more question: How do I call the original function in my hooked version?

Comment: Thank you! Just to clarify: running `real_usleep = (usleep_f)dlsym(libc_so, "usleep");` will call the function?

Comment: No, that will look up the real function.  `real_usleep(x)` will call it.

Comment: Regarding the original method, I was getting gcc error `nosleep.c:4:5: error: conflicting types for 'sleep'` - looking at the manual for sleep `man sleep.3` it now returns an unsigned int, so I changed that and it compiled as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sure. I'm speaking hypothetically, since I don't have the program or the source, but `nanosleep()` is probably represented by a call to `sleep()`. If it were me, I'd use `objdump -d` to disassemble the code, and see if I can use that and the information acquired through `strace` to pinpoint the specific call to `sleep()` (or its variant), such as the calls surrounding it, etc. This is not trivial, but possible. If you can do that, you can see what parameters are passed in (on x86, they'd be pushed on the stack; on 64-bit, they'd be in registers), and then modify those directly. If they're variables, you can also track them down that way.

In order to actually edit the binary if you find the location you want to edit, you can use a program like `bvi`, or even use `xxd` to output the file, change the word, and then use its `-r` option to get a binary again.

**Edit:** Now it's possible (I forget if it's all the time) that the offsets in `xxd` differ from the ones you see in `objdump`. This is because the offsets shown in `objdump` are virtual addresses, and the ones shown in `xxd` are the actual offsets in the file. To reconcile this, you can use `readelf -WS` to show the section headers of the file, like so (with `/bin/ls` as an example):

```
$ readelf -WS /bin/ls | grep .text
[13] .text  PROGBITS  0000000000402460 002460 00c248 00  AX  0   0 16
```

Here, the relevant information is the two columns after `PROGBITS`. `402460` is the **virtual address** of the `.text` section, which is where the executable code in the binary is stored, and `2460` is the **actual offset in the file** to where this section is found. Subtract the two, and you get `400000` (that's hex, of course). Now, if you go back to `objdump`, you should find a few lines like so:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000402460 <close_stdout-0x6460>:
```

So you see that `.text` starts at `402460` here? Look for this function (and data) in the file at `(404260 - 400000)`, or `2460`, and you should find it! So what you're looking for in `xxd` is the location of the virtual address in objdump minus the offset you found, like above. Sorry for forgetting about this!

Comment: I found the function using objdump, but I can't find it in the hex dump provided by xxd :S

Comment: @DanielS If you found it in objdump, you'll have the address. You should be able to find the same location with `xxd`; doesn't it show offsets on the left?

Comment: The numbers on the left of the output of xxd are different than the ones from objdump :(

Comment: There isn't concise information on the internet regarding this, so this question will be helpful for those looking to do the same thing. Thank you for the detailed answer!